# when does my for statement not run through

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to set up a way to make sure EditText's and Radio groups are filled out. I have set up a boolean to say if it's true or false that something is missing.

For some reason it's not running past my `System.out.println(test0.2)` and then starts printing again on `System.out.println(isEmpty)`. The `scanState` is an enum that will be in the code below.

```
public enum ScanState {
    scanning,
    empty,
    stopped
}

ScanState scanState;

public boolean checkForms() {
    boolean isEmpty = false;
    scanState = ScanState.scanning;
    ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    final int childCount = linearLayout.getChildCount();
    View element = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        element = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        System.out.println(i);
        switch (scanState) {
            case scanning:
                System.out.println("test0.2");
                if (element instanceof EditText) {
                    System.out.println("test0.3");
                    EditText editText = (EditText) element;
                    if (editText.getText() == null) {
                        scrollView.scrollTo(0, editText.getTop() + 10);
                        isEmpty = true;
                        scanState = ScanState.empty;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (element instanceof RadioGroup) {
                    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) element;
                    System.out.println("test1");
                    if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
                        System.out.println("test2");
                        scrollView.scrollTo(0, radioGroup.getTop());
                        isEmpty = true;
                        scanState = ScanState.empty;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                scanState = ScanState.stopped;
                break;
            case empty:
                break;
            case stopped:
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(isEmpty);
    return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: Is child count greater than 0? The only reason that first print statement would not print is if it never enters the for loop.

Comment: yes its greater than zero. The logcats lists it

Comment: and what is the first element of that layout? if it is neither an `EditText` nor a `RadioGroup`, `scanState` will be set to `stopped`, never changed and so further loop iterations will do nothing

Comment: the first element is a TextView. How would i change it for it fix that problem then?